# docker container running as per logs from Jenkins pipeline but when going to ec2 server, no running containers are showing

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2, dockerfile, cicd

I have created a CICD Pipeline using Jenkins and when I run the Jenkins job, it gives the output as successful as shown in image but when I login to the ec2 instance, and manually check for any running containers or images, it shows none. Also I am unable to access the application on mapped port on ec2 instance, even though the port is open in security group. I am not using any NACL or local Linux firewall. UFW is disabled. OS is Ubuntu 22.04

when I pull the image locally on my laptop and run a docker container from this image, it runs properly.
I have checked and confirmed that the pipeline stage is connected to correct EC2 instance since i am able to fetch details and IP address of EC2 instance. python version is 3.12 and flask is version 3.

Code :-
Jenkinsfile code:-

pipeline {
agent any

```
environment {
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION = 'ap-south-1'
}

stages {
    stage('Deploy to AWS EC2') {
        steps {
            script {
                withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'my-app-server-ssh-id', keyFileVariable: 'awsPrivateKey', usernameVariable: 'awsUsername')]) {
                   sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i \${awsPrivateKey} \${awsUsername}@<ec2-instance-public-ip> \
                   docker image ls && \
                   docker ps -a && \
                   docker system prune -af && \
                   docker ps -a && \
                   docker pull alexxy21/flask-todo-app:latest && \
                   docker image ls && \
                   docker run -p 5000:5000 alexxy21/flask-todo-app:latest && \
                   docker ps"
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

post {
    success {
        echo 'Build succeeded!'
    }
    failure {
        echo 'Build failed!'
    }
    always {  
        sh 'docker logout'     
    }  
}
```

[Output of Pipeline logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zDAw.png)

[EC2 cli output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGP2f.png)

What is the issue?

I was expecting the container to be running on the EC2 instance and the application to be accessible on mapped port.

Comment: You don't have a `docker run -d` option, so the `sh` step is blocked on the container completing.  You seem to have included a link to an image file instead of the Jenkins logs so it's a little hard to tell what's failing, but my guess is the `sh` step times out, and when it stops, the foreground container is killed too.

Comment: Not sure, but it may be a possibility that your docker commands were executed on Jenkins slave, which were supposed to run on ec2-instance-public-ip.

Comment: @DavidMaze - I have already tried with docker run -d but  it did not work so I tried with many different things.  I am new to Jenkins so I don't know how and where can u get the logs. the logs I shared earlier is the console input from the CICD pipeline running on Jenkins Master server. I thought maybe the image was not built properly but i tested it separately by manually pulling and running it and it works fine.

Comment: @RahulSharma - Thanks to your suggestion. I checked and found out that the container is created and running on the Jenkins server itself. the issue as per me is related to the jenkins user that is running the pipeline. There is no jenkins user on destination EC2 instance. I created a jenkins user on destination instance and gave it sudo rights but it did not work. Anything else you can suggest me?

Comment: @RahulSharma Thanks again. The problem got solved after finding the cause. So the issue was related to logging into the server and running docker commands on it. What fixed it was change in pipeline code.

Comment: script {
                withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'my-app-server-ssh-id', keyFileVariable: 'awsPrivateKey', usernameVariable: 'awsUsername')]) {
                    sh """
                    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i \${awsPrivateKey} \${awsUsername}@instance-ip \
                    'ip addr && whoami && docker pull alexxy21/flask-todo-app && docker run -d -p 80:5000 alexxy21/flask-todo-app'
                    """
                }
            }